# Monitoring remote system using Jconsole

Tags: java, unix, remote-access, jconsole

I am connecting to remote Unix system using putty and .ppk key file.
Now i want to monitor this remote unix system using Jconsole.
On remote system jmx port is enabled on 8080.
I have its ip address ,jmx port ,username and .ppk file.How could i connect or remotely monitor using Jconsole?
through putty i am connected to remote system using tunneling .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the remote port 8080 cannot directly be connected to or you question would be mood, so:

Having a "regular" terminal connection won't help you connect any networked application -- you want to set up a **SSH tunnel** to forward the remote host's port 8080 to your local host's port :8080 (or any other available port), see http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html (espcially Figure 3)

Comment: i have set up ssh tunnel to forword host's port 8080 to localhost:1108 using putty.i am able to connect to remote system using puttty.But when i say Jconsole localhost:1108 it shwos message "connection to localhost:1108 did not succed"

Comment: Are you able to `telnet`, `nc`, or `nmap` your `localhost:1108` and get a connection? Maybe you confused the local/remote tunnel -- make sure you do a *local* port forward, i.e. the PuTTY equivalent of `ssh -L 1080:remotehost:8080 remotehost`.